# Changing "Preferred device" in Game Controllers doesn't save the choice

Tags: windows-11, game-controller

I'm trying to change the preferred device in Windows 11 to no avail. When I select Bluetooth LE XINPUT and click OK, next time I open this dialog, it is set back to ROG CHAKRAM X no matter what I do. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

[image: Controller settings]

Comment: Why is this tagged with an unrelated Xbox360 tag?